# How to access one model from a different view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models named `tasks` and `category`. I need to access category table data from tasks view

`views/tasks/_task.html.erb`

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><%= task.description %></td>
    <td><%= task.category_id %></td>
    <td><%= task.status %></td>
  </tr> 
</tbody>
```

each `category_id` has corresponding name stored in Category table. So instead of displaying category_id (eg: 1,2,3..etc), I need to pull the corresponding `name` from `Category` table. (`id:name` ==> 1: Todo, 2: shopping..etc)

Comment: Can you post the corresponding controller action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have your model set the right way something like this

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  ...
end
```

then in your view you should be able to say

```
<td><%= task.category.name %></td>
```

I hope I got the question right 
and also the answer

Happy hacking

Comment: I used `<%= task.category.name %>` in the view and it worked.